# change color after condition in vue.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

wen i use this script :

```
<div class="card-content">
        <vue-tabs class="row" direction="vertical" value="Description">       
        <div v-for="(item, index) in siteObject.line_info" :key="index">
            <v-tab :title="siteObject.line_info[index].lineid">
                <div class="description text-left">
                    <small v-for="(field, key) in item" :key="key">
                        <strong>{{ key }}</strong> {{ field }}<br>
                    </small>
                </div>
            </v-tab>
        </div>        
      </vue-tabs>
      </div>
```

i have this result:
nsn 0102799121
upk 173.0-1/1
status ACTIVE
lex_id 78EFFEFVS
hdf_port 
product_id PPS515818292
technology VDSL
access_type BBCSNaked

how can i show the status wen is active red and he inactive grey ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably looking for conditional class bindings.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

```
<div class="static"
 v-bind:class="{ active: item.STATUS, 'text-danger': !item.Active}">
</div>
```

In your case I'd recommend making a function that receives the item. And returns true / false if the string === ACTIVE or not. Something like:

```
<div class="static"
 v-bind:class="{ active: statusIsActiveFunction(item.STATUS), 'text-danger': !statusIsActiveFunction(item.STATUS)}">
</div>
```

Comment: should i put this before this my <div> ?

Comment: you can place the v-bind:class anywhere you want.

Comment: i did it but i have no result something is wrong can yo help me please

Comment: Did you create a function in the component? Update your quesiton with the rest of your component.

Comment: any help please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174019/discussion-between-sofiane-and-devilscomrade).